# Distance between two cities on Earth

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation, geodesy

> Barcelona (Spain) has the coordinates (approx): $\theta = 2^\circ$, $\phi = 41^\circ$, and New York has the coordinates: $\theta = −74^\circ$, $\phi = 41^\circ$. Notice that both cities lie on the same latitude, which makes the calculations easier. For your calculations, use Earth’s radius $R = 6378$ km, and give all your result in kilometers.
>
> 1. On most maps, the naive ‘straight line’ between Barcelona and New York lies on the line of latitude $\phi = 41^\circ$. What is the distance between the two cities along this line?
> 2. What is the actual shortest distance between those two cities?
>
>    Hint: Notice that it is determined by the angle Barcelona–Earth’s center–New York. Use the fact that the angle $\psi$ between two unit vectors $nA$ and $nB$ satisfies $\cos \psi = nA \cdot nB$.
>
>    Hint: Observe that both curves are parts of circles.  By using this, you can avoid integration altogether.

For the first part, I'm trying to take the Euclidean distance. 
\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& R\cos\theta\cos\phi \\
y &=& R\cos\theta\sin\phi \\
z &=& R\sin\theta,
\end{eqnarray}
Using this, I get coordinates for NY and Barcelona.

New York: $(x, y, z) = (2620.58, 421.01, 5799)$

Barcelona: $(x, y, z) = (-1081.34, -173.72, 6283.26)$

If I try to find the distance by the equation

\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}
\end{eqnarray}

I get 3780 km.

Am I doing this right? I feel a bit lost because this "naive" distance differs so greatly from the real one (ie 6157 km)

The Euler-Lagrange equation is this: 
\begin{eqnarray}ϑ˙^2 cos ϕ sin ϕ/
\sqrt{ϕ˙^2 + ϑ˙^2 cos^2 ϕ}
+
d/dt  ϕ˙^2
\sqrt{ϕ˙^2 + ϑ˙^2 cos^2 ϕ}
= 0
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Nice question, but how does the euler-lagrange-equation come into play here ?

Comment: What you calculated is the distance if we would go through the earth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Be careful. All angles are measured in radians. In accord with the question $\phi$ means the latitude ($=\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{polar angle}$) and $\theta$ means the longitude (azimuth angle).

If one considers the Earth being a ball, the shortest path is:
$$
d=R\arccos(\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2+\cos\phi_1\cos\phi_2\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)),
$$
the argument of $\arccos$ being the scalar product of unit vectors directed from the Earth center to the points on the surface.

The "naive path" for $\phi_1=\phi_2\equiv\phi$ has length:
$$
d^*=R(\theta_2-\theta_1)\cos\phi.
$$

> In the last expression $0\le\theta_2-\theta_1\le\pi$ is assumed. Generally $\arccos\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)$ can be used instead.

Comment: For the naive path, won't d = 0 since \begin{eqnarray}
\phi_2=\phi_1=41


and 


  \phi_2-\phi_1 = 0 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: @mathinthecity NO.  By mistake I interchanged the meaning of $\theta $ and $\phi $ compared with your question, so that in my expressions $\theta $ means latitude and $\phi $ means longitude. This is however in accord with the spherical coordinate system introduced by you (so that you also have interchanged the meaning). If you insist I can change the names back to original notation.

Comment: According to this website, I'm not getting the correct answer. It's not even close.. 
https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: The website reports the distance 5856 km. My expression with R=6371 km gives  6157 km. I would not say "it's not even close". The deviation is probably caused by the fact that Earth is not a ball.

Comment: Which expression are you referring to, the 1st or 2nd?

Comment: The first one. The second gives 6378 km.

Comment: d* = 6371*cos(41*76) = 5715
The website gives 6157KM

Comment: Am I inserting the values wrong?

Comment: Now I see your problem with understanding. $(\phi_2-\phi_1)$ is not in argument of $\cos$. It is a multiplicative factor equal to $\pi*76/180$.

Comment: Oh i see! Why do we convert it to radians?

Comment: Do we not convert the 41 to radian?

Comment: @mathinthecity I have rewritten the formula to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: We should convert it to radians to compute the length. $\arccos$ in my first expression gives results also in radians.

Comment: I see! But still for the first formula, I set my calculator to degrees and input the following values:

R*arccos(sin^2(41) +cos^2(41)*cos(76))

Still don't get the same answer as you

Comment: @mathinthecity Check if the calculator gives the result of $\arccos$ in radians. If not divide it by 180 and multiply by π. I have rewritten the answer using the angle definitions from the question.

Comment: @mathinthecity I have checked the distance from New-York to Barcelona. It appears to be 6167 km, practically coinciding with the result of the first formula, whereas its approximation on the website you linked is in a heavy error.

Comment: +1 Because the [great circle distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) is certainly relevant. *But*, the question seems to indicated that a more elementary technique should be used.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thank you very much for the vote. But I disagree with suggestion about  "a more elementary technique". Quite contrary, the sentence "Use the fact that the angle ψ between two unit vectors nA and nB satisfies cosψ=nA⋅nB." (which I did not notice while answering the question) implies that exactly the "great circle distance formula" was expected.

Answer (score 2):

Use that chord length and the Earth's radius to determine the arc length around the curved path.

Answer (score 1):

Using the distance equation you will get the "straight line distance" if you bored a hole through the earth.

The radius of the $41^\circ$ parallel is $R\cos 41^\circ$

And the distance a person would travel if they followed this arc would be this radius times the longitude traveled in radians: $(R\cos 41)(\frac {76 \pi}{180})$

The great circle path...

$a\cdot b = \|a\|\|b\| \cos \psi\\
(R\cos 74^\circ\cos 41^\circ, R\cos 74^\circ\sin 41^\circ, R\sin 41^\circ)\cdot(R\cos -2^\circ\cos 41^\circ, R\sin -2^\circ\cos 41^\circ, R\sin 41^\circ) = R^2(\cos 76^\circ\cos^2 41^\circ + \sin^2 41^\circ)\\
\psi = \arccos (\cos 76\sin^2 41 + \cos^2 41)\\
D = R\psi$

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain how you came up with Rsin41? Thanks!

Comment: Also when I use $D = R\psi$ , the answer doesn't equal to the actual distance (https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: I apologize, I had my sines and my cosines flipped.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the Earth along its center $O$ and the two cities $N$ and $B$ to get a circle with the radius $R$ and the angle $\measuredangle BON=76^\circ$.

a) The length of the chord $BN$ is:
$$BN=\sqrt{NO^2+BO^2-2NO\cdot BO\cdot \cos{\measuredangle BON}}=\\
\sqrt{2\cdot 6378^2-2\cdot 6378^2\cdot \cos{76^\circ}}\approx 7853.38 \ \text{km}.$$
Note: The Cosine Theorem is applied in the triangle $\Delta BON$.

b) 
The length of the arc $BN$ is:
$$l_{BN}=2\pi R\cdot \frac{\alpha^\circ}{360^\circ}=2\pi\cdot 6378\cdot \frac{76^\circ}{360^\circ}\approx 8460.1 \ \text{km}.$$